# If statement not detecting string same as other string

Tags: python, string

```py
import re
def click(event):
    username = username_entry.get()
    password = password_entry.get()
    print(f"Clicked, User = {username}")
    expression = r'(.*).....$'  # Match any characters before the last 5 characters
    masked_password = re.sub(expression, r'\1*****', password)  # Substitute last 5 characters with '*'
    print(f"Masked Password = {masked_password}")
    if password.lower() == str('password'):
        print("Password: GOOD")
        print(f"'{password.lower()}' = 'password'?")
        if any(char.isdigit() for char in password):
            print("Int: GOOD")
            if len(password) >= 8:
                print("Length: GOOD")
            else:
                print("Length: BAD")
        else:
            print("Int: BAD")
    else:
        print("Please fill out all the required fields")
```

Result:

```
Clicked, User = Username
Masked Password = Pas*****
Password: GOOD
'password' = 'password'?
Int: BAD
```

The password seems to be "password", so why isnt it detecting that?

I have no idea why this isnt working, it should say "Please fill out all the required fields"

Comment: `'password'` is a `str` already, why do you call `str()` again? Moreover your code does not do anything in its current form.

Comment: "The password seems to be "password", so why isnt it detecting that?".  It **is** detecting that.  Any other password will make your first `if` false and then you'd see "Please fill out...".

Comment: I know, it should have been if password != "password", im deleteing the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues:
1)
Change

```
if password.lower() == str('password'):
```

to

```
if password.lower() != str('password'):
```

This is you main problem, the code goes in the wrong direction due to this

2. Invert the condition or the code inside the statement where you check for any digit:

The any() function returns True if any element of an iterable is True. If not, it returns False. As none of the char is digit in `password`, you will go to the else statement

Should work like this:

```
 if any(char.isdigit() for char in password):
     print("Int: BAD")
 else:
     print("Int: GOOD")
     if len(password) >= 8:
         print("Length: GOOD")
     else:
         print("Length: BAD")
```